# Find $P(b^2\ge4ac)$ given that $a,b,c\in\{-9,-8,\dots,8,9\},a\ne0$

Tags: probability

I was doing some review on probability and came across the following exercise:

> A quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is copied by a typist. However, the numbers
>   standing for a, b and c are blurred and she can only see that they are integers of one
>   digit. What is the probability that the equation she types has real roots?

Quadratic equations have real roots when the determinant is greater than or equal to $0$. Therefore $$P(\text{real roots})=P(b^2-4ac\ge0)=P(b^2\ge4ac)$$
My original thoughts were to find $1-P\left(\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2<4ac\right)$ where I would break it into cases where $b$ ranges from $0$ to $9$. I would then find out how many cases $4ac$ was larger than $b^2$ and divide it by $19^2*18$ (since $a\ne0$). When I found out it would be too tedious I thought of a possible geometric interpretation. Maybe the the probability could be expressed as ratios between volumes or something similar. When that seemed to over-complicate the problem I figured I was probably approaching it incorrectly.

Any hints or nudges in the general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $P(b^2 \geq 4ac) = P(ac \leq 0) + P(b^2 \geq 4ac \, \vert ac >0) P(ac >0)$ might help you reduce the number of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where $|4ac| > b^2$ the probability is 1/2 by changing the sign of $c$.

In the case where $|4ac| \leq b^2$ and $a \neq 0$, the probability is $1$.

In the case where $a=0$ one has to decide how to interpret the words "real roots".   The simplest is to exclude equations of degree less than 2 (probability 1/19).  If a single root of multiplicity one is allowed, or the equation $0=0$, then the answer will be different.

The main part of the problem is then to count the cases where $b^2 < 4|ac|$. If $|ac| > 20$ there is no constraint on $b$.  There are a finite number of possibilities with $|ac| \leq 20$ and they can be accounted for by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. The exercise book gives the answer $\frac{107}{576}$, maybe that can tell us whether they considered the case when $a=0$. Just one question, what does c.r. mean?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Was eating lunch :P Could you complete your argument so I could see how you would proceed? I'm still not entirely sure on how to arrive at the final result.

Comment: The denominator of 576 suggests that $b$ and $c$ may be required to be nonzero.  For each value of $|ac| \leq 20$ the number of possible $b$ can be computed; add this up over the possible pairs $(a,c)$.